# What is a "Chosson Shas"?

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, jewish-books, chassan-groom

My community has a local email list where people post items that they want or items for sale, etc.

This morning, I saw a post requesting an *Oz Vehadar Chosson Shas*.

I must be an early-aged "A.K." What is a "chosson shas"? What makes a sha"s set specifically appropriate or specialized for a groom that any other sha"s couldn't otherwise do? How popular is this type of sha"s? What does this cost, typically?

(Excuse the barrage of questions, but, perhaps, I need to prepare myself quickly for when my kids get married!)

**Note:** In some quick research, I see that there is a "Vilna" Chosson Sha"s also. So, in answering, please address the general concept of what a "chosson sha"s" may be doing differently - not specifically any version / publisher. If, **additionally**, you want to include info about one version vs. another, that's fine.

From [this site](http://miriedel93.wixsite.com/jerusalem-leather/chosson-shas) it's leather-bound and has the chassan's name on it. Is that the only difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Chasson Shas is usually just an even larger edition of the regular large Shas. So there will be a pocket sized Shas, a small 8-9 inch Shas. The large standard 11-12 inches. And then the super sized 14-15 inch Chasson Shas.

There are also available fancy leather embossed covers available as well.

The Oz Vehadar site [here](http://www.oz-vehadar.com/en/department/13/shas-chatanim) has some samples.

Comment: Anecdotally I did not want a chasson shas when I got married. I always used the small edition and even a the standard big size was not something I liked. I mentioned this to my Rosh Yeshiva and he said he felt it was important to get a big chasson shas. He added jokingly that there will be more room in the margins for chidushim. A close Rabbi friend of mine added that he felt it was important as it will be a major piece of the home decor, setting the tone of the home with a large religious piece. (When used, of course:)

Comment: A full Tur still adds to the decor and is more useful than an extra Shas you'll never touch.

Comment: Agreed. That was the parenthetical statement at the end. Having an unused one might be worse than none at all.

Comment: "major piece of the home décor" - I have to restrain myself from reacting to this thought. The main piece of the home décor is really your family's behavior esp. that of your kids. I'll leave it at that, for now.

Comment: @DanF Making this a focal point of the house is meant to influence the behavior of the family. That sounds strange to you? Some people have big screens. Some people have big Shas.

Comment: At the very least it allows the in-laws to walk in and think their son-in-law is a Talmid Chakham because he has such a big Gemara section. The bigger your books the more you know, right?

Comment: @Double that just gets back to the old point. Looking used is what makes it a beautiful centerpiece.

Comment: Well, I can't argue with your last point. And, that's assuming that one not only uses it, but applies what he has learned. Then again, I'm still wondering what's wrong with a non-chosson shas that's significantly cheaper. DoubleAA's point is "right on the money". It sounds like what makes this a "chosson shas" over the other ones is its size and adding décor. Fine, I guess that aspect is important to many people, and the giant sha"s does the trick. It is better "décor" IMO than the big screen TV.

Comment: @user6591 you want a source for this idea that a used Shas is beautiful? I once heard someone quote Shir Hashirim 1:5 to that effect שְׁחוֹרָ֤ה אֲנִי֙ וְֽנָאוָ֔ה׃ - "dark [as a well used book] and beautiful"

Comment: @mbloch That is very nice. I was also thinking about the Chassam Sofer who reassured someone that the browning of his esrog due to use was not a chesaron in hidur but rather that was the hiddur.

Comment: @mbloch FWIW, I have a few very used machzorim in my home. Browned pages, some loose from the binding. But it's my gem, esp. since I know exactly who used them and what he did with them. And the best benchers are the ones with wine stains and the candle wax in them!

Comment: @DanF This past Pesach someone spilled marinade from the chicken pan onto my haggadah! And I don't think I have a single bentcher which _doesn't_ have wine stains and candle wax galore!

Answer (score 10):

Generally speaking, a Chosson Shas is a set of larger Gemarahs - a couple of inches taller and wider than the typical full-sized Gemarah you would find in your shul. The type is thus bigger and easier to read (on the down side they're also significantly heavier). The price will vary according to the bells and whistles of the particular set (such as the ones you mentioned), but the price range will generally be somewhere in the $700 - $1000 range.

I have heard an explanation given that this shas is supposed to be a gift to the groom that he will be able to use for the rest of his life. So he's given a set with extra large type that he will still be able to read easily even when eventually his eyesight worsens with old age (though how he'll be able to lift it at that age I can't tell you).

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I'm not sure I completely "get it", but, perhaps within a few years, I'll be pressured into, literally, "getting" it. It makes me wonder, though, what's wrong with the ones in the Bet Midrash, esp. for the many chattanim who spend most of the day learning in them, anyway.

Comment: @DanF - It's like a leather siddur. Why would you purchase one when siddurim almost always become torn up? Gemoras need to be something you won't be afraid to open because it might "get torn."

Comment: @ezra I think you may be missing my point. People sometimes feel pressured into buying this. I was just wondering why that trend is there. I.e., what makes this type of sha"s worth the pressure? Even after the explanation, I still don't understand the pressure. Then, again, I'm also not out to change people's minds about it, either.

Comment: @DanF - When I get married, I will be happy with _any_ Shas set. :-P

Comment: @ezra No reason to wait that long for happiness. You can either get married now, or get a sha"s set now. If you want, you can buy the chosson sha"s even **before** you get married. Not a bad idea, actually ;-)

Comment: My wife bought me a large leather-bound edition as a chosson shas.  Initially, I thought it was excessively extravagant & I didn't need a fancy Shas.  With time, I adjusted to enjoying that it has slightly nicer paper, wide margins for note taking etc.  That said, I am still reluctant to carry a volume anywhere or use it if I think it will get messy at all.  A friend has a chosson shas and on a separate shelf a mismatched set of used volumes.

Comment: @DanF - Actually, a very good idea, LOL. There's no way I want to make my future kallah/in-laws pay for an expensive Shas set. I think I'd rather get a nice tallis godol...

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen Offhand thinking - Sha"s is meant to be used, as stated, before. If you prize your own Sha"s, I think you prize it enough to bring it to your Bet Medrash. If nothing else, you have one place to write all your notes, esp. if you're doing that in a *chevruta* or attending a shiur. Easier than transferring notes. Analogous - my parents covered their furniture in plastic b/c they always wanted it to look nice for everyone else. My in-laws intentionally didn't cover the furniture because they wanted everyone to know they're welcome to use it!

Comment: @DanF I’d imagine the initial reason for this stems from that fact that it was a very expensive item back in the day and not everyone had or could afford it, so, seemingly the parents or in-laws etc bought it, and the tradition stuck.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Per my responses to the above comments - I have two general principles, here - 1) I don't see any sensible reason for anyone to spend a lot of money on anything where a good cheaper substitute will suffice and 2) Prior to buying any sha"s at all, I think the buyer should have some sense if the chattan will actually end up using this, or is it just remaining on the shelf as decoration and to give others a false impression?