# What is the difference in Sha"s types; Oz V'hadar, Zecher Chanoch, N'harda'ah(נהרדעא)?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, talmud-bavli

I am looking to purchase a true [Chossen Shas](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83694/11501), and I see various editions or publications.
I am familiar with the classic Vilna Shaas, but I see many sets in either Oz V'hadar עוז והדר, Zecher Chanoch זכר חנוך, and also N'harda'ah נהרדעא.
The more I search, the more contrasting and varied information I find.
Can anyone shed some light?
Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Howard and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works? Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: The end of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/94214/13438

Comment: if you look at them in a store you might see if a particular printing has a cleaner font, commas (or is menukad) and the selection of meforshim.

Comment: The main difference between them is which commentaries are printed in the margins and in the back of the volume, I believe.

Comment: Really you ought to just go into a Seforim store and check them out yourself, if possible. Do you live in a remote location?

Comment: For what's it worth, I found a place where you can see sample pages for the [Oz Vehadar](http://seforimsets.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=294&filter_name=oz%20vehad) and the [Zecher Chanoch](http://seforimsets.com/index.php?route=product/product&filter_name=zecher+chanoch&product_id=622) sets.

Comment: They are all basically the same, so it really just boils down to personal preference.